# Why does my MacBook's monitor go to maximum brightness when waking up from sleep?

Tags: macbook-pro, sleep-wake, display

I have my MacBook connected to an external monitor (via HDMI), and the brightness of MacBook monitor is set to 50% of max brightness . I usually put my display to sleep when I leave my computer for a break, and everytime I wake it up, the MacBook monitor will be set to maximum again.

Any idea how do I fix it so that when I wake up the display, I do not need to adjust the screen brightness down again?

I am running Lion on an early 2009 MacBook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to reset the [System Management Controller](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3964).

> #### Resetting the SMC on Mac portables with a battery you can remove
>
> 1. Shut down the computer.
> 2. Disconnect the MagSafe power adapter from the computer, if it's connected.
> 3. Remove the battery.
> 4. Press and hold the power button for 5 seconds.
> 5. Release the power button.
> 6. Reconnect the battery and MagSafe power adapter.
> 7. Press the power button to turn on the computer.